# ActionMailer outside Rails

Tags: ruby, actionmailer

I am trying to send an email using ActionMailer outside Rails and got stuck at `Missing template` error.
I have a folder structure like this.

```
mailer/app/mailers/welcome_email.rb
mailer/app/views/welcome_email/welcome.html.erb
mailer/mailer.rb
```

I have a config file where I have this line:

mailer/initializers/config.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.view_paths = File.expand_path('../../app/views/', __FILE__)
```

(I don't understand why I need to add this extra '../', to be honest because, the path is 'one folder up' and then '/app/views'. If I don't do this it finds '/initializers/app/views/').

```
File.expand_path('../../app/views/', __FILE__)
```

returns `"/home/jedrek/workspace/rubysamples/mailer/app/views"` which seems fine. ActionMailer should then find `welcome_email/welcome.html.erb` template there but when I run `mailer.rb` I get an error

```
Missing template welcome_email/welcome
Searched in: (ActionView::MissingTemplate)
  * "/home/jedrek/workspace/rubysamples/mailer/app/views"
```

Why doesn't it find the file in `/app/views/welcome_email/welcome.html.erb`?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your mailer name is MyMailer ? Then you should have a folder named my_mailer in views folder and inside it file named welcome.html.erb

Comment: @SaqibShahzad sorry, my Mailer is WelcomeEmail, my bad.

Comment: and what is mailer/mailer.rb

Comment: In this file I simply require 'welcome_email' and call it `WelcomeEmail.welcome.deliver_now`

Comment: Rename your welcome_email directory in views folder to welcome_email_mailer and it should work.

Comment: You need the extra "../" because you need one to remove the file name and the other to remove the current directory. You could also do `File.expand_path('../app/views/', __dir__)`

Comment: @SaqibShahzad I renamed the folder welcome_email to welcome_email_mailer but it dosn't work

Answer (score 0):

Rename your `welcome_email` directory in views folder to `welcome_email_mailer` and it should work

Comment: You know what? I'm stupid :P I had `format.html` in the actual mailer but I didn't have the file welcome.txt.erb which would explain why it said `Missing template welcome_email/welcome with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:text], ...`